# opensuse KDE 11.4 - How to edit $HOME/.bashrc

Tags: opensuse, kde-4

Just install opensuse 11.x kde into my Lennovo X60, kick out the ms window. The must function, input Chinese can't work. When start IBus, it shows following message. How to edit $HOME/.bashrc? Tried run this command in bash:

edit .bashrc, but I don't know how to save the file.

Thanks. Forgive my foolishness.

```
IBus 已經成功啟動！如果您無法使用 IBus，請將下列代碼加入到 $HOME/.bashrc 中，並重新登入桌面。

  export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

  export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

  export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus

IBus startup successfully! If you can't use IBus, pls. add the following code to $HOME/.bashrc, then restart desktop. export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

  export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

  export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to linux then you might like to try the "nano" editor. Run "nano .bashrc". To save files you do CTRL-X.

Comment: To save you do CTRL-O, to exit you do CTRL-X. If you exit without saving, it'll ask.

Comment: Oh yeah. Good point :)